# How to use bootstrap modal in ionic 3?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, ionic3, jstree

I need to call bootstrap modal inside below method. It uses `jstree` and implemented platfrom is Ionic 3. It fires this error "TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery**(...).modal is not a function" when modal method is called. Please do help me to find a solution for this error.

```
loadTreeContent() :void{

    var d01_base_url = '';
    var d01_loading_url = '';
    var d01_base_folder_path = '';
    var d01_doc_item = '';

    $(function () {

      $('#d01-documents').jstree({
        "core": {
          "multiple": true, //No multi select
          "themes": {
            "variant": "large",
            "responsive": true,
            'stripes': true
          },
          "animation": 500,
          'data': {
            'url': d01_base_url + d01_loading_url,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': function (node) { //Getting data
              if (node.original == undefined)
                return {
                  'id': node.id,
                  'level': 0,
                  'operation': 'get_node',
                  'base_folder_path': d01_base_folder_path,
                  'doc_tree': d01_doc_item
                };
              else {
                var l = node.original;
                return {
                  'id': node.id,
                  'level': node.original.level,
                  'operation': 'get_node',
                  'base_folder_path': d01_base_folder_path,
                  'doc_tree': d01_doc_item
                };
              }
            }
          },
          'check_callback': function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            if (more && more.dnd && more.pos !== 'i') {
              return false;
            }
            if (operation === "move_node" || operation === "copy_node") {
              if (this.get_node(node).parent === this.get_node(node_parent).id) {
                return false;
              }
            }
            if (node_parent.type != 'default') { //Unless dropping to a folder
              return false;
            }
            if (node.original.permissions.edit != 1) { //Check source's edit permissions before moving
              //data.instance.refresh();
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
        },
        'types': {
          'file': { 'icon': d01_base_url + 'assets/img/file-16.png' }
        },
        "plugins": ["search", "sort", "dnd", "types"]

      }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {  

         //Method to be called.

      }).on('move_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        $.get(d01_base_url + d01_loading_url, {
          'id': data.node.id,
          'drop_folder': data.parent,
          'operation': 'move_node',
          'base_folder_path': d01_base_folder_path,
          'doc_tree': d01_doc_item,
          'drag_parent': data.old_parent
        }).done(function (d) {
          if (d.status == 'failed') {
            //alert('Sorry! You cannot move this folder/file. Because it will affect the permissions of other permission groups. So you must change them before this movement.');
            alert(d.msg);
          } else if (d.status == 'success') {
            alert('Success!\nDebug msg:\n\n' + d.msg);
          }
          data.instance.refresh();
          $("#d01-documents").jstree("open_all");
        }).fail(function () {
          alert('Sorry! Movement process failed, unexpectedly.');
          data.instance.refresh();
          $("#d01-documents").jstree("open_all");
        });
      }).on('ready.jstree', function () {
        $("#d01-documents").jstree("open_all");
      });
    }); //Function

  }
```